# Can you make an Ember.TextField wait until change to update its value binding?

Tags: javascript, date, ember.js

I extended an `Ember.TextField` to include a date picker. A function that observes the text field’s `value` attempts to parse the string in the text field and update a date property. This is all fine and good when you use the date picker, but if you were to try to type a date into the box, it goes crazy because the `value` gets updated on every keydown (or keyup or whatever Ember’s default event to update the value bindings for a `TextField`), and it immediately re-updates the value of the text field with the nicely-formatted date string that came from what it just parsed. Example:

1. Input says `10/26/2014`
2. You insert your cursor after `2014` and hit backspace
3. The `value` has changed, so a handler parses `10/26/201` and updates a `date` property
4. The `date` property has changed, so a handler formats the date as `MM/d/yyyy` and sets the `value`
5. The input now says `10/26/0201`

Rather than changing the way those handlers work, all my problems would be solved if I could tell Ember to update the `value` binding when the input’s `change` event fires, rather than trying to update everything on every keystroke. I know this can  be done in AngularJS and Knockout, but I can’t find anything about it for Ember.

**EDIT**

I know I can change the way my code works to avoid this specific problem. At this point, I’m more interested for purposes of edification, in a yes-or-no answer that specifically addresses the question that is the title of this post. I’m starting to think the answer is no, but wanted to poll the community.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post that may offer some solutions about [Date Pickers And Validation In Ember](http://www.jarrodctaylor.com/posts/Date-Picker-And-Validation-In-Ember/) with examples here is one of the [JSBins](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/viguqidu/1) from the post.

Comment: While this doesn’t answer my theoretical question (I’m starting to think the answer is just “No”), it’s helpful to my problem in this instance. Thanks, and +1.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own extension of text field component and add the `change` callback.

```
App.DateTextComponent = Em.TextField.extend({
  change: function(event){
    var value = this.get('value');
    // massage data
    value += "foo";
    this.set('value', value);
  }
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/suzami/2/edit

If you really want to get a call when the value changes after the fact, don't observe the value, use actions.

```
App.DateTextComponent = Em.TextField.extend({
  change: function(event){
    var value = this.get('value');
    this.sendAction('changed', value);
  }
});

{{date-text value=foo changed='fooChanged'}}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/suzami/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This does not answer my question—I know how to listen for the change event, but that doesn’t prevent the bindings from updating every keystroke. It doesn’t have any bearing on when a function that `.observes('value')` fires.

Comment: Ember is all about reusability, instead of having some external thing fix up your date field, define a specialized component that fixes it and you can reuse it over and over. (example updated)

Comment: I just saw your update, no, you can't using the default text field, you could write your own implementation that does that if you'd prefer.